# display: table row does not allow scroll

Tags: html, css

I am currently designing a book website and on the right-hand side want to have a "Table of contents" which is in a fixed position and scrollable. I set the header for my website to "display: table-row" and similarly did so with the table of contents and its internal elements. (A header and a the scrollable list of chapters) As I understand it, display: table row should make a div element fill the remaining height and only the remaining height. [1] However, in this case, the content continues offscreen instead of allowing the user to scroll through it. (You can see the problem on this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/chrmon2/9wzjckvn/6/)

My css:

```
#container {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#header {
  background: blue;
  display: table-row;
}
#toc h1 {
  background: red;
  display: table-row;
}
#toc #content {
  background: yellow;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: table-row;
}
```

Is this not a capability of display: table-row or am I doing something wrong? Thanks

1. https://www.whitebyte.info/programming/css/how-to-make-a-div-take-the-remaining-height

Comment: What specifically do you need `display: table-row` for? The capabilities of a `table-row` element are very limited in terms of styling.
Edit: Sorry, I didn't catch it at first glance. In what way do you want the `table-row`s to fill the remaining height? E.G. do you want them all the grow/shrink uniformly, do you want the last element to grow, etc.

Comment: This solution seemed to be the best one for my situation. Am I incorrect in thinking it causes divs to fill the remaining height?

Comment: I assume that you want all the `div`s to expand to fill the space available, and if the space available is too small you want to show a scrollbar. I'll write an answer to that effect.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I've been quite busy lately.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the effect you want is as follows:

- When there is remaining space, stretch the table of contents items;
- When the space is too small, begin scrolling.

This is an ideal application of [CSS Flexboxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). Flexboxes allow you to define how items stretch (or don't), how they align with each other, how they wrap etc.

In this case, we're going to use flexboxes for all the `div`s in this example.

```
.container, .toc, .content {
    display: flex;              /* begins flexbox layout */
    flex-direction: column;     /* Flexboxes can be aligned from left-to-right
                                   or from top-to-bottom. In this case, we want
                                   them to be top-to-bottom. */
    flex-grow: 1;               /* On .container, this does nothing. However, for
                                   children of Flexboxes, this tells them to grow
                                   if any space is still available. */
    min-height: 0;              /* For a more complicated reason, this is necessary
                                   to make flexboxes scroll correctly. This needs
                                   to be set on all the flexboxes in this example. */
}

.toc .content .item {
    flex-grow: 1;               /* Make items grow when there is room available */
}

.content {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

You can see the effects of this [at this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9wzjckvn/16/).

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `display: table-row` from `#toc #content` and add this :

```
 #content{
 max-height:200px;
 }
```

height can be as per your requirement.